# Passing a object from view to controller with typo3 6.2.9

Tags: php, view, controller, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I faced the following problem in Typo3 6.2.9:

When I pass some objects to the controller by using f:link action and arguments, the objects will arrive at the controller but he does not register them as they what I have send. For a better explanation here the single code sections:

at the partial:

```
<f:link.action action="new" controller="ForeignProductMeasuring" arguments="{planRow : planRow, plan:plan}">neue Dosierung anlegen</f:link.action>
```

the generated link in the site:

```
"index.php?id=1&tx_desinfektionsplan_desinfektionsplan%5BplanRow%5D=12&tx_desinfektionsplan_desinfektionsplan%5Bplan%5D=16&tx_desinfektionsplan_desinfektionsplan%5Baction%5D=new&tx_desinfektionsplan_desinfektionsplan%5Bcontroller%5D=ForeignProductMeasuring&cHash=2adafaba9c56b134d4d5ae382ee5d57b"
```

what shows the the arguments are correct in my opinion.

Here the action at the controller:

```
public function newAction(\Orochemie\Desinfektionsplan\Domain\Model\ForeignProductMeasuring $newForeignProductMeasuring = NULL,
\Orochemie\Desinfektionsplan\Domain\Model\PlanRow $planRow,
\Orochemie\Desinfektionsplan\Domain\Model\Plan $plan) {

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump( $this->request->getArguments());
$this->view->assign('newForeignProductMeasuring',$newForeignProductMeasuring);
$this->view->assign('planRow', $planRow);
$this->view->assign('plan', $plan);

}
```

The error looks like this:

```
#1: PHP Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
Orochemie\Desinfektionsplan\Controller\ForeignProductMeasuringController::newAction()
must be an instance of Orochemie\Desinfektionsplan\Domain\Model\PlanRow, 
none given in /kunden/137629_70806/typo3/typo3conf/ext/desinfektionsplan/Classes/Controller/ForeignProductMeasuringController.php line 46
```

For me it looks like that he doesn't knows the objects which he gets. But if I check the arguments with $this->request->getArguments() then I see that all arguments arrive at the controller.

Does anybody has a idea of what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you define your params in the PHPDoc annotations?

```
/**
 * @param \Orochemie\Desinfektionsplan\Domain\Model\ForeignProductMeasuring newForeignProductMeasuring
 * @param \Orochemie\Desinfektionsplan\Domain\Model\PlanRow $planRow
 * @param \Orochemie\Desinfektionsplan\Domain\Model\Plan $plan
 * @return void
 */
 public function newAction(\Orochemie\Desinfektionsplan\Domain\Model\ForeignProductMeasuring $newForeignProductMeasuring = NULL,
    \Orochemie\Desinfektionsplan\Domain\Model\PlanRow $planRow,
    \Orochemie\Desinfektionsplan\Domain\Model\Plan $plan) {

    ...

}
```

These are pretty important for the ObjectMapper.